# After read the Stream I cant save file from fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a FileUpload control, and when I click a button I want to save the FileUpload file to a File in the server.

I check I am getting a file from the FileUpload with data, but when I try to save it in the server, the file created is empty. What Am I doing wrong?

I had updatepanels at the beginning, but now there is not any update panel.

```
                string string1, string2, string3;
                bool bool1= false, bool2= false, bool3= false;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fuSubirPlantilla.PostedFile.InputStream))
                {
                    string contenidoPlantilla = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    bool1= contenidoPlantilla.Contains("[tag1]");
                    bool2= contenidoPlantilla.Contains("[tag2]");
                    bool3= contenidoPlantilla.Contains("[tag3]");
                }

                if (bool1 && bool2 && bool3)
                {
                    string1 = dropdown1.SelectedValue;
                    string2 = dropdown2.SelectedValue;
                    string3 = dropdown3.SelectedValue;

                    string filename= "filename1_" + string1 + "_" + string2 + "_" + string3 + ".html";

                    string folder = Server.MapPath( "~/XML_MI/Common/").Replace("/", "\\");
                    // Me aseguro de que termine en \\
                    folder = folder.EndsWith("\\") ? folder : folder + "\\";
                    // Antes de guardar el archivo
                    string folderFilePath = $"{folder}{filename}";
                    fuSubirPlantilla.SaveAs(folderFilePath);
                    //Stream stream = fuSubirPlantilla.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    //using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(folderFilePath))
                    //{
                    //    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    //}
                }
                else
                {
                    // Error
                }
```

I tried, as you can see, another approach, but it still not working

```
                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(folderFilePath))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
```

The problem is related with I read all Stream at the beginning [**reader.ReadToEnd()**](If I dont, I dont have the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to move all your code which is now going after `using` block inside the block. When you go out of the `using` the `StreamReader` is disposed and it might dispose and close the `InputStream` as well, thus you save nothing to the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Rewind is not available and Seek is not working.

Comment: @EliasMP, 
ok, then could you also try to move all your code which is now going after "using" block inside the block? Because when you go out of the "using" the StreamReader is disposed and it might dispose and close the InputStream as well, thus you save nothing to the file.

Comment: It works... Thanks mate. If you edit your answer I will rate it. :)